# Listview not getting populated with data from individual lists in c#

Tags: c#, list, listview

I have lists which store parsed data from sqlite columns. I want to show these lists in a **listview** to the user. They click a button and the list view (currently has 3 columns) should show these 3 lists and their contents.

**Problem: I click the button and the list view doesn't get populated with anything. Nothing happens**.

I'm new to programming.. so here's my code:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(); 
   foreach (object o in MaxLen)
   {
      lvi.SubItems.Add(o.ToString());
   }
   foreach (object a in SeqIrregularities)
   {
      lvi.SubItems.Add(a.ToString()); 
   }
   foreach (object b in PercentPopList)
   {
      lvi.SubItems.Add(b.ToString()); 
   }
}
```

On a side note, if anyone wants to see how I actually populated my lists , it's here:

```
string sql4 = "SELECT * FROM abc";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql4, sqlite_conn);

// The datareader allows us to read the table abc row by row
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
   // Parse Seq column
   int seq;
   if (int.TryParse(reader["Seq"].ToString(), out seq))
      if (seq > 30)
      {
         SeqIrregularities.Add(seq);
         seq1 = true;
      }

   // Parse Max Length Column
   int maxlen;
   if (int.TryParse(reader["MaxLen"].ToString(), out maxlen))
      if (maxlen > 30.00)
      {
         MaxLen.Add(maxlen);
         maxlen1 = true;
      }

   // Parse % Populated Column 
   int PercentPop;
   if (int.TryParse(reader["Percnt"].ToString(), out PercentPop))
      if(PercentPop == 0 || PercentPop > 100 || PercentPop < 80) // decimals?
      {
         PercentPopList.Add(PercentPop);
      }
```

Comment: You don't appear to be adding your ListViewItem to your ListView anywhere in the code you supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Add `ListViewItem` object `lvi` to the `Listview` to get the Populated 3 List's

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(); 
   foreach (object o in MaxLen)
   {
      lvi.SubItems.Add(o.ToString());
   }

   foreach (object a in SeqIrregularities)
   {
      lvi.SubItems.Add(a.ToString()); 
   }
   foreach (object b in PercentPopList)
   {
      lvi.SubItems.Add(b.ToString()); 
   }

ListView1.Items.Add(lvi);//here you need to add
}
```